# Preventing stack overflow while calculating term in sequence

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a binary sequence that follows a specific logic such that it starts with 0 and

```
nth term = sequence of (n-1)th term + 0 + inverse(reverse(n-1)th term)
```

eg:

```
0
0 + 0 + 1
001 + 0 + 011
0010011 + 0 + 0011011
```

Here, I need to find out the nth term of the kth sequence. My take:

```
static int foo(long n, int k) { //n-th element (indexed from 0) in k-th sequence
    long length = (2 << k) - 1; //computes 2^(k+1)-1
    if(n == length/2) return 0;
    if(n < length/2) return foo(n, k-1);
    return 1 - foo(length - n - 1, k-1);
}
```

But if I try to calculate 2378421387489th element in 50th sequence, it fails at StackOverflow. How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

You should add some preconditions check:

```
static int foo(long n, int k) { //n-th element (indexed from 0) in k-th sequence
    long length = (2 << k) - 1; //computes 2^(k+1)-1
    if(n > length) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Out of bounds");
    if(n == length/2) return 0;
    if(n < length/2) return foo(n, k-1);
    return 1 - foo(length - n - 1, k-1);
}
```

The correct implementation of your function is:

```
static int foo(long n, int k) { //n-th element (indexed from 0) in k-th sequence
    if(n==0 && k==0) return 0;
    long length = (1L << k) - 1;
    if(n < length) return foo(n, k-1);
    if(n == length) return 0;
    return 1 - foo(n-length-1, k-1);
}
```

Comment: What's your input n and k?

Comment: in the 50th sequence there are 1125899906842623  terms, so my input for n and k is `50` and `1125899906842622`

Answer (score -1):

overflow error occurs when heapsize is exceeded(This is commonly seen in recursion programs when the number of sub function calls is high). 
personally i would avoid using recursion.

Try changing the Recursion code to a loop and re run.

Comment: Stack overflow occurs when the *stack* size is exceeded. It is almost invariably due to a bug, rather than the mere use of recursion.